# android, gradle, how to force to use a old com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging: dependence version

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dependencies, gradle-dependencies

Having dependency in the app

```
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
```

But the app has dependency on other sdk, which depends on new version

```
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
```

and the app is not ready for `21.1.0` (got `task.exception` = `java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR` on

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
                    .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task -> ...task.exception }
```

So would like to force to use `20.0.1`.

and tried

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    }
}
```

it does not work, and tried (hope the group==`com.google.firebase` and name ==`firebase-messaging` are used correctly):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase' && requested.name == 'firebase-messaging') {
            details.useVersion '20.0.1'
        }
    }
}
```

still it resolved to the newer `21.1.0`:

[image]

and also see in the top level it has {strictly}, not sure where it is from:
[image]